# $(x^2 + 1)(x - 6) = 0$ How is the solution equal to 6?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The answer for this equation $(x^2 + 1)(x - 6) = 0$ is $x=6.$

May I know the technique? I am new here, please teach me how to style the equation too.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a differential equation. Moreover this question may be missing info depending on the sophistication of answer you require.

Comment: The quick and dirty guide to math formatting is found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you have $ab=0$, this means that $a=0$, $b=0$, or both $a=b=0$.

Looking at the first term, we see that $x^2+1=0$ has no real solutions, but $x-6=0\implies x=6$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ab = 0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

$$(x^2 + 1)(x - 6) = 0$$

This implies that either $x^2 + 1 = 0$ or $x - 6 = 0$.

$x^2 + 1 = 0$ does not have any real solutions for $x$. (Here, $x = \{i, -i\}$, but I assume your problem takes place in the reals.)

$x - 6 = 0$ has the solution $x = 6$.

Therefore, the only real solution is $x = 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is already factored into the product of $x^2+1$ and $x-6$. A product becomes $0$ when *at least one* of the factors is equal to $0$.

The first factor, $x^2+1$, can never be $0$ (why?); so the equation is only satisfied when the other factor, $x-6$, is equal to $0$. This happens when $x=6$.